# Cancel installation of the Application but Silent Application is not stop its installation

Tags: installshield

I created a setup file using InstallShield application and it has some per-requisite conditions for installing the application like .NET framework 4.0.

Now whenever user install this application at that time first we check that Framework is installed on that machine or not. If it is not installed then i installed it silently which is already packaged with MSI. For silent installation i use '**/q /s /norestart**' parameters.

But the problem is suppose user quite the installation of my application then after installation of the .NET framework is not getting cancel.

What should I do..? Is there any need to change installation parameters..? Or may i need to add parameters for .NET framework application while it is installed in silent mode..?

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these command line parameters:

```
/passive /norestart
```

This way the .NET Framework installer will show a progress bar and the user can cancel its install. There is no way for the EXE bootstrapper to automatically cancel a third-party installation.

Comment: Thnx for reply.... I have a problem if i use the command line parameters suggested by you. application is not installation in silent mode. also the previous problem is still exist.

Comment: What do you mean? What is the exact behavior?

Comment: Mean to say If i use "/passive /norestart" then prerequisites are not getting installed in silent mode. I need the Silent Installation, Process Path and cancel functionality for every prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

As a prerequisite, only MSI installations can be cancelled, and then only if the prerequisite is set to capture the MSI's progress. In all other cases, there is no way for InstallShield to know how to cancel a prerequisite's setup, silent or otherwise.